# Vue.js watched data chang twice with only one request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="layui-input-block" style="width:510px;">
            <form class="layui-form" action="">
                <select v-model="form.entrCode">
                    <option value="">please select an entry</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            action: '',
            form: {
                entrCode: '',
            }
        },
        watch: {
            action: function (val) {
                if (val !== "add"){
                    var vm = this;
                    //$.get("/park/GetLEDDtl", { areaId: vm.form.code }, function (rs) {
                    //    vm.form = rs;
                    //}, "json");

                    //simulate setting on ajax.success
                    vm.form = { "entrCode": "20" };
                }
            },
            "form.entrCode": function (val, old) {
                alert("【entryCode changed】 new:" + val + "    old:" + old);
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.action = "edit";
        }
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Please look at my code. I've only set `app.form = object` once, why there are two value changed be watched?

First, it changes from `''` to '20', which is what I'm expected, but suddenly it changes from `20` to `undefined`.

(The code patsed I commented ajax request, and set value directly.)

What just happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option with the value you are setting the variable to. The select object cannot be synced up to show the value, so it reverts the value to undefined.